# Neo4J reduce in a Map

Tags: neo4j, cypher, reduce, reduction

Is it possible to reduce a Collection in a Map in a Cypher query?

For example:

```
MATCH (n) WHERE n.foo =~ "ba[rz]" 
RETURN reduce({}, barz IN collect(n.foo) | {`(barz)`:[n]} )
```

Input:

```
[
    {foo: 'bar'},
    {foo: 'baz', some: 'thing'},
    {foo: 'baz', or: 'other'}
]
```

Output:

```
{
    bar: [
        {foo: 'bar'}
    ],
    baz: [
        {foo: 'baz', some: 'thing'},
        {foo: 'baz', or: 'other'}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not (yet), the best you can do for now is two-element collections as name-value pairs (tuples)

Comment: There is a group_by command that exists in other languages, that could work here as well